# Proving irregularity using Myhill-Nerode theorem

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, automated-theorem-proving

I'm trying to prove that the following language is irregular using the Myhill-Nerode theorem

$$
L = \{ w\space\epsilon \{a,b,c\}^* | \#_b(w) > (\#_a(w) + \#_c(w))! \}
$$

While it's completely clear that it's irregular using basic logic (the fact a regular expression can't "remember") and using the pumping lemma, I am completely stuck trying to show it with the theorem.

I've tried dividing up the:
$$
(\#_a(w) + \#_c(w))! \to (\#_a(w) + \#_c(w))*(\#_a(w) + \#_c(w)-1)!
$$
I've tried creating sub groups by:
$$
\frac{(\#_b(w))}{(\#_a(w) + \#_c(w))}
$$
But all to no avail.

Suggestions and/or help would be greatly appreciated :)